# How can I avoid duplicating the following code?

Tags: java

```
List<Widget> widgets = widgetDao.retrieveWidgets(widgetBatchSize, 0);
createWidgets(widgets);

for (int offset = widgetBatchSize; widgets.size() >= widgetBatchSize; 
        offset +=  widgetBatchSize) {
    widgets = widgetDao.retrieveWidgets(widgetBatchSize, offset);
    createWidgets(widgets);
}
```

It feels wrong that I'm duplicating the processing code going on before and within the loop.  How can I avoid duplicating this code?

Comment: What does this code actually do?

Comment: Start at `0` in your for loop instead??

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a `do-while` loop instead.

Comment: Get used to it.  You can waste hours trying to restructure something like that, and will likely introduce errors in the process.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out in the comments, use a `do...while` loop instead:

```
List<Widget> widgets;
int offset = 0;
do {
    widgets = widgetDao.retrieveWidgets(widgetBatchSize, offset);
    createWidgets(widgets);
    offset += widgetBatchSize;
} while (widgets.size() >= widgetBatchSize);
```